# C: bit operations on a variable-length bit string

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm doing some bit operations on a variable-length bit string.

I defined a function `setBits(char *res, int x, int y)` that should work on that bit string passed by the `*res` variable, given a `x` and `y` (just to mention, I'm trying to implement something like a Bloom filter using 8 bits per x):

```
void setBits(char *res, int x, int y)
{
  *res |= x << (y * 8)
}
```

E.g. given the following x-y-vectors `{0,0} ; {0,1} ; {1,2} ; {2,3}`, I expect a bit string like this (or vice-versa depending whether little- or big-endian, but that isn't important right now):

```
0000 0010 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So the lowest 8 bits should come from `{0,0}`, the second 8 bits from `{0,1}`, the next 8 bits come from `{1,2}` and the last from `{2,3}`.

Unfortunately, and I don't seem to get the reason for that, `setBits` always returns only the last result (in this case i.e. the bit string from `{2,3}`). I debugged the code and realized that `*res` is always 0 - but why? What am I doing wrong? Is it that I chose `char*` that it doesn't work or am I completely missing something very stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming 8-bit chars, the maximum value you can store in `*res` is `0xff` i.e. `(1<<8)-1`.

Consider what happens when you call `setBits` for `x=1`, `y=1`

```
x << (y * 8) == 1 << (1 * 8)
             == 1 << 8
             == 0x100
```

`*res` is an 8-bit value so can only store the bottom 8 bits of this calculation.  For any non-zero value of `y`, the bits which can be stored in `*res` are guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: Oh! So it is really the `char*`? What could I do then? The length of the bit-string should be variable. Pass a `char[]`, instead?

Comment: Yea, why don't you try `char[]` which is a byte array and see

Comment: @navititious Sorry, I'll struggle to offer more specific advice.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and don't know what a Bloom filter is

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the maximum I can store in a `char` is limited by `2^8` bits; but actually I'm using the `char*` pointer only to point to some memory I `calloc`'ed beforehand such that there is enough space to do the operation from above. So in any case it is limited? `char[]` unfortunately did not help.

Comment: The idea behind Bloom filter is not that important here. What I'm really trying to do is to build the bit string like in the example above, where for each vector given ´{0,0} ; {0,1} ; {1,2} ; {2,3}´, the second value of the vector is used to get the position within the bit string and the first value is the value that should be inserted in the bit string.

Comment: If you figure out the max size of the values you want to store, you could allocate your array in terms of a larger type such as `short` or `int` and pass a pointer to that type into `setBits`

Comment: Ok, so I tried with ´y < 4´ and used ´int´ (since ´4 * 8 = 32´ fits in an ´int´) and it worked; so you were completely right on what the problem is! But what do I do if I really don't know the max size? What if, in the vector ´{x, y}´, y might grow to 1000 and I would need a data type that supports 1 KB?

Comment: Sounds like you should reconsider how you store your data.  Storing 2*n bytes per vector and just storing the numbers directly will be smaller than any variant of the approach in your question.  If you'd like advice on how best to store a series of vectors, it'd be best to ask this as a new question, preferably with a fair bit of additional info